# jQuery - Pass Event Listener's Selector to Plugin

Tags: jquery, debugging, object

I am making my own simple `jquery` plugin.
But I'm in the beginning stages, and I'm only focusing on things that help me with debugging my custom plugin.

At this point I'm firing an event listener, and the element is an `<a>`
The plugin is only meant to Identify another element, nothing fancy.

**index.html**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="funclass" id="funhref">Click Me</a>
<br />
<table id="randomElement">
  <tr>
   <td>Testing table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#funhref").on('click', function (event) {

        $("#randomElement").identifyElement();

    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

**identifyElement.js**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        identifyElement: function(options) {

                    // goal 1:  (identify the type of element)
                    console.log( $.type($(this)) ); // returns "object"

                    // goal 2:  (what's the element that fired off the 'click' method? 

        }
    })//eof extend()
})(jQuery);
```

This is as far as I got.

For all you hard-core debuggers, you can see I'm working to know as much as possible about the elements I'm working with.  (totally helps with future projects)

**Goal 1:** 
In this case, I'd love to know that `#randomElement` is an html table.  If it were something else, then obviously I'd like to print to the `console` what it is, or if it's not recognized.

-you can see `console.log( $.type($(this)) );`  which returns "object" but I'm wanting it to return "table"

**Goal 2:**
I clicked an `href` to fire the event and trigger the plugin to do it's magic.  I'd love to print to the console that information too.  (I never know when I may need to know what spawns an event)

Again, I'm not building a jquery plugin to do anything except practice debugging and identifying elements I'm working with.

Can anyone help me with my 2 unfinished goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working fiddle for goals 1 and 2. I dropped your options parameter for now, replaced with event param

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cV7/2/

```
 $("a#funhref").on('click', function (event) {

    $("#randomElement").identifyElement(event);

}); 


(function ($) {
$.fn.extend({
    identifyElement: function(event) {

    // goal 1:  (identify the type of element)
    console.log( this[0].tagName ); 

     // goal 2: what's the element that fired off the 'click' method? 
    console.log( event.target );
      }
   })//eof extend()
   })(jQuery);
```

UPDATE:

here is a version using your options param:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cV7/4/

```
 $("a#funhref").on('click', function (event) {

   $("#randomElement").identifyElement({event : event});

}); 


 (function ($) {
 $.fn.extend({
    identifyElement: function(options) {

    // goal 1:  (identify the type of element)
    console.log( this[0].tagName ); // returns "object"

   // goal 2:  (what's the element that fired off the 'click' method? 
   console.log( options.event.target );
    }
 })//eof extend()
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great examples!  I'm digging the jsfiddle options version you made!

Comment: Glad to help. Try using each() in the plugin to support more than one element

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .is() method to look for a specific tag.

If you pass the event object that jquery gives in the click() callback, event.target will be the element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

Goal 1:

```
this[0].tagName
```

will return "TABLE".

Goal 2: I don't think you can get the `A` element in your plugin. If you want this, you need to require that the caller pass `this` or the event object as a parameter.

Comment: this.tagName wont work in his context because 'this' is jQuerry object in the plugin's context. would have to use prop() or this[0].tagName